# Error: React Context is unavailable in Server Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, next.js, next-auth

Please help me fix this error: When I run the application in Next.js I am getting this message:

> Error: React Context is unavailable in Server Components

```
import { useSession } from "next-auth/react";
import prisma from "@/lib/prisma";
import { ChatbotClient } from "./components/chatbot-client";
import { redirect } from "next/navigation";

interface ChatbotIdPageProps {
  params: {
    chatbotId: string;
  };
}

const ChatbotIdPage = async ({ params }: ChatbotIdPageProps) => {
  const { data: session } = useSession();

  if (!session?.user) {
    redirect("/demo");
  }

  const userId = JSON.stringify(session.user);

  const chatbot = await prisma.chatbot.findUnique({
    where: {
      id: params.chatbotId,
      userId: userId,
    },
  });

  return <ChatbotClient initialData={chatbot} />;
};

export default ChatbotIdPage;
```

Answer (score 5):

Instead of [`useSession`](https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/client#usesession) which works only in [Client Components](https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/react-essentials#client-components) (with `"use client"` at the top), use [`getServerSession`](https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/nextjs#getserversession) since you are in a [Server Component](https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/react-essentials#server-components):

```
import { getServerSession } from "next-auth/next";
import { authOptions } from "app/api/auth/[...nextauth]"; // ⚠️ Make sure this is the correct path
import { useSession } from "next-auth/react";
import prisma from "@/lib/prisma";
import { ChatbotClient } from "./components/chatbot-client";
import { redirect } from "next/navigation";

interface ChatbotIdPageProps {
  params: {
    chatbotId: string;
  };
}

const ChatbotIdPage = async ({ params }: ChatbotIdPageProps) => {
  const session = await getServerSession(authOptions);

  if (!session?.user) {
    redirect("/demo");
  }

  const userId = JSON.stringify(session.user);

  const chatbot = await prisma.chatbot.findUnique({
    where: {
      id: params.chatbotId,
      userId: userId,
    },
  });

  return <ChatbotClient initialData={chatbot} />;
};

export default ChatbotIdPage;
```

Side note, if you try to add `"use client"` and stick with `useSession`, the component function cannot be `async`, and there you can fetch data only in a `useEffect`.

Comment: in my case reaon was different,i had typo `"use Client"; `with capital C in Client, changed to `"use client";` and worked

Answer (score 2):

In Next 13, anything that uses React.Context (even your libraries) will need to be a Client component. You can achieve this by having "use client" at the top of your page.

```
"use client" 
import { useSession } from "next-auth/react";
import prisma from "@/lib/prisma";
import { ChatbotClient } from "./components/chatbot-client";
import { redirect } from "next/navigation";

interface ChatbotIdPageProps {
  params: {
    chatbotId: string;
  };
}

const ChatbotIdPage = async ({ params }: ChatbotIdPageProps) => {
  const { data: session } = useSession();

  if (!session?.user) {
    redirect("/demo");
  }

  const userId = JSON.stringify(session.user);

  const chatbot = await prisma.chatbot.findUnique({
    where: {
      id: params.chatbotId,
      userId: userId,
    },
  });

  return <ChatbotClient initialData={chatbot} />;
};

export default ChatbotIdPage;
```

Comment: this leads to this error

"Prevent client components from being async functions. See: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/no-async-client-component"